# Isometric Projection

Tags: java, isometric

I'm working on a Java 2.5D game, but I'm having an issue with terrain tiles displaying properly. I've followed several tutorials, surfed StackOverflow, etc, but something still seems to be missing.

Each tile stores its coordinates in top-down 2D view, so that it originally looks like this:
[image: Before Projection]

When I try to project them isometrically, it looks like this (obviously incorrect):
[image: After Projection]

Here is the relevant code:

```
    static int getIsoX(int X, int Y)
    {
        return (X-Y) - xOrientation;
    }


    static int getIsoY(int X, int Y)
    {
        return ((X+Y)/2) - yOrientation;
    }

    static void rotateBuffer()
    {
        double axis = (double) GameWorld.GRID_SIZE/2;
        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180.0, axis, axis);
        op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    }

    void draw(Graphics2D G)
    {
        int x = GameWorld.getIsoX(xCoord, yCoord);
        int y = GameWorld.getIsoY(xCoord, yCoord);
        G.drawImage(op.filter(sprite, null), x, y, null);
    }
```

xOrientation and yOrientation refer to the coordinates of the camera. The final isometric view should appear such that the tiles are neatly up against one another:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens if you only draw one tile? I suspect either the tiles are being cropped by the rotation, or they are getting overwritten.

Comment: Your rotating the images but they are retaining their size, so they crop at the original rectangle, cutting off the edges.

Comment: You haven't included enough code.  It looks like (as others have said) you are rotating individual tiles.  You need to apply the operation to the G2D so the whole assembly is transformed.  Anyway, for a true isometric you need a rotation _and_ a foreshortening (scale by < 1) on the vertical axis.

Comment: Awesome, I rescaled the transform and then changed the rotate axis point to account for the rescale ratio. It works now. Thanks, guys!

Comment: Also, if you'd like the full video game isometric projection, rotate down the x axis until you are viewing from 26.6 degrees before you apply the 45 degree `transform.rotate` and you'll get something more like this: http://pixelcurse.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/isometric_pixel_art_8.jpg